# Stack two div then float left with CSS

Tags: css

I'd like to have 5 divs (1, 2, 3, ...) displayed like this:

```
+---+  +---+  +---+
| 1 |  |   |  | 4 |
+---+  | 3 |  +---+
| 2 |  |   |  | 5 |
+---+  +---+  +---+
```

where 3's height is **twice** as mush as 1, 2, 4, 5's ones.

Is there a way to position them like this without wrapping 1, 2 and 4, 5 into divs ?

Here's my HTML markup :

```
<div class="AlaOracles">

    <div class="AlaOracle">
        <img src="http://mywebsite.ru/wp-content/uploads/shutterstock_132379904.jpg" alt="mange l'écran" />
        <div>
            <div class="Header">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Some text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Body">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Some text<br />
                        [button link="#" color="orange" size="medium" type="flat" shape="square" target="_parent" title=" Test "] Mode de cuisson [/button]
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="AlaOracle">
        <img src="http://mywebsite.ru/wp-content/uploads/shutterstock_132379904.jpg" alt="mange l'écran" />
        <div>
            <div class="Header">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Some text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Body">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Some text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="AlaOracle Bigger">
        <img src="http://mywebsite.ru/wp-content/uploads/shutterstock_132379904.jpg" alt="mange l'écran" />
        <div>
            <div class="Header">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Some text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Body">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Some text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="AlaOracle">
        <img src="http://mywebsite.ru/wp-content/uploads/shutterstock_132379904.jpg" alt="mange l'écran" />
        <div>
            <div class="Header">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Some text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Body">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Some text<br />
                        [button link="#" color="orange" size="medium" type="flat" shape="square" target="_parent" title=" Test "] Mode de cuisson [/button]
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="AlaOracle">
        <img src="http://mywebsite.ru/wp-content/uploads/shutterstock_132379904.jpg" alt="mange l'écran" />
        <div>
            <div class="Header">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Some text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Body">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        Some text<br />
                        [button link="#" color="orange" size="medium" type="flat" shape="square" target="_parent" title=" Test "] Mode de cuisson [/button]
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why do you not want to wrap 1+2 and 4+5 in divs?

Comment: I'd like to keep the structure as simple as possible. So I could easily display it differently with other CSS.

Comment: @RubyvanSoelen I tried mixing float left/right. I couldn't figure how pseudo classes ::before/after would fit in the picture, etc. I can't possibly list everything that won't do what I need.

Comment: I hope the edit that I've made is what you want. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Please include your current markup, and tag this with the markup language you're using as well (HTML, presumably).

Comment: If wouldn't mind using javascript, take a look at [*masonry*](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Answer (score 4):

## Using Flexbox

**Compatibility:** [IE11 and all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). Safari is supported with the `-webkit-` prefix.

If the lack of legacy browser support is not a problem, this is a good way to achieve this flexibility without using wrappers or javascript.

### Let's make this

[image: Screenshot]

### The HTML

Couldn't be simpler:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

### The CSS

- the body (or a single outer wrapper) is given `display: flex`, `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap` so that the flex items will wrap themselves into columns. It is given an appropriate min and max width and is centered with `margin: 0 auto`
- the divs are given `flex: 1 1 50%` this tells the div to have a default value of 50% and allow it to grow and shrink, even with a pixel value.
- the middle column is given `flex: 1 1 100%` and it will be twice as tall. It can easily be selected using just `nth-child(3)`

[Here is an excellent guide over on CSS Tricks.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

### Complete Example

```css
body {
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
body > div {
  background: #F00;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}
body > div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #F90;
}
body > div:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  margin: 0 20px;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div>top left</div>
<div>bottom left</div>
<div>middle</div>
<div>top right</div>
<div>bottom right</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kLym7mga/)?

```css
div.one {
  background-color: #f00;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
div.two {
  background-color: #0f0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
div.group-one {
  float: left;
}
div.group-two {
  float: left;
}
div.three {
  background-color: #00f;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
}
div.group-three {
  float: left;
}
div.four {
  background-color: #ff0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
div.five {
  background-color: #0ff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
```

```html
<div class="group-one">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
<div class="group-two">
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
<div class="group-three">
  <div class="four"></div>
  <div class="five"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid the wrapping.

Comment: Well I wouldn't know why you'd even mind wrapping, but fine I tried my best again http://jsfiddle.net/kLym7mga/1/

Comment: I might end up using positioning if I can't find a way. Not just relatives as you did though, It creates a gap under the divs.

Comment: well I tried, gave several working answers but you don't seem to accept any of them, that's cool but I'm just gonna go ahead and stop answering

Comment: @RubyvanSoelen - Please include the relevant code in your answer with an explanation. Links can go dead and this is a good example as jsFiddle is down for me at the moment :) Also remember that the questioner does not need to accept any answer, even if it is a perfect fit.